# where can i find crash logs for ad-hoc iphone applications on windows 7

Tags: iphone, windows-7, itunes, crash-reports, adhoc

My ad-hoc beta testers reported a crash, that i cannot reproduce on my device. How can i retrieve crash logs from their device? They use itunes on windows 7. What is the path to crash logs of iphone applications on windows 7?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\Logs\CrashReporter\MobileDevice\*Device Name*

Comment: thanks for answering, can you post a full path? like c:\users... thanks again

Comment: `%USERPROFILE%` will usually be `C:\Users\UserName`.

Comment: nope, couldn't find it in AppData. The only folder it has was LocalLow or something like that... Is it supposed to store there only with a certain itunes version?

Comment: Crash logs are only stored on the computer after a sync with iTunes. Make sure the device is synced before looking for them.

Comment: `AppData\Roaming` will _always_ exist.  It might be a hidden folder, though.

Comment: i saw, that indeed it's the path, but couldn't come to it through the finder. How do i make a folder visible? Thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: You go to the Folder's Properties, click Advanced, and uncheck Hidden.  You can also go to Folder Options and select Show Hidden Files and Folders.